# What is the interpretation of a wave function of the Universe in Hawking's no boundary proposal?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, wavefunction, quantum-gravity, boundary-conditions

In the path integral formalism we have an in state $\Psi_{in}[\phi]$ and and out state  and we find the amplitude for going from one to the other:

$$\Delta[\Psi_{in},\Psi_{out}] = \int \Psi_{in}[\phi]\Psi_{out}[\phi]e^{i S[\phi]} D\phi$$

I am trying to understand quantum cosmology. Hawking describes his wave function of the universe as:

$$\Psi_{out}[h] = \int_{\partial g=h} e^{-S[g]} Dg $$

There is no "in" state since we assume the Universe is spatially closed and space-time is like a sphere with time starting at the "south pole".

But what's confusing me is that, unlike in the previous case where $\Psi_{out}[\phi]$ can take on many forms (for instance being highly peaked at various field configurations of our choosing), $\Psi[h]$ has only one form defined by the functional integral. Hence there can be no such thing as $\Delta[\Psi_{in},\Psi_{out}]$ in quantum cosmology since all states are the same and $\Psi_{in}=\Psi_{out}$. Is this related to the **"problem of time?"**

Instead I read that you can have $\Psi[h,h']$ which is a kind of amplitude for going from one geometry to another where you sum over 4D geometries bounded by both h and h'.

Is it true that in quantum cosmology $\Psi[h]$ can only have one form? It would be like a wave function only having one distribution!

Is there a simple way to show that the wave functional cannot change?

**Edit**

I think I understand a bit more. If $\Psi_{in}[g]=\delta[g(0)]$ and $\Psi_{out}[g]=\delta[g(1)-h]$ then $\Delta[\Psi_{in},\Psi_{out}] = \Phi[h]$ which is the wave functional of the Universe which satisfies the Wheeler-de-Witt equation. And so in general the amplitude for a particular distribution must be:

$$\Delta[\Psi_{out}] = \int \Psi_{out}[g] \Phi[g] Dg$$

I guess that makes sense. Perhaps I was mixing up states and wave functions.

**PS**

Is it true that there is only one quantum state of the Universe. In Hawking's first paper he says talks of the quantum state being the "ground state". Is this not the view now? Is there just a single quantum state?

Comment: Since your mastery of QM's notation exceeds my own, I'd hesitate to post an outright answer; however, since you're asking about "time", you might want to take a look at the influential philosopher Huw Price's 1996 book titled "Time's Arrow and Archimedes' Point", published by Oxford:  On its p.86-93, Price discusses Hawking's wave function, and explains how, although he'd first thought that it resolved the asymmetry of time through a corresponding asymmetry in a region of space having the opposite temporal direction, he rejected that view for subtle reasons which he specifies.

Comment: I am not sure I get the question (a very frequent occurrence with me), but as of the question of ``is there only one quantum state?", the thing is that our working is in _perturbative_ quantum gravity, due to which writing states like $\Psi \sim \int [\phi ]_{i}[g]_{i} |0\rangle $ gives us states that may not be invariant under de Sitter isometries. You instead divide with the gauge group volume (see Moncrief, Higuchi, Suvrat et al) to get the modified norm. So you can solve WDW to get dS-invariant states. I will try answering the question tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is that the wave functional is equal to the transition function from the big bang to a geometry:

$$\Psi[h] = \Delta[h,S_0]$$

Comment: In that sense it would be a nucleation formula? I think it should also be noted not everyone agrees with this approach for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one state under a wave function unless the wave function has been determined, which is possible. The universe should have arose in many multiple possible ways even in a ground state.